# How to prevent socket from getting closed in http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am receiving this error `Error: write EPIPE` while making http request in nodejs . I am using http package, how can I prevent this should i pass `keep-alive` header true in the request.

```
const req = server.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`data reci`)

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`body`)
    })
  })

  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`error`)
  })

  req.write(sample_data)
  req.end()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 1.1 was not designed to keep a connection open. It's designed to make a request, get an aswer and then end.

HTTP 2.0 however is a little different and can be used with more control over the request/response and data. ([slides](https://de.slideshare.net/mnot/what-http20-will-do-for-you))

But if you really want an open connection I would suggest checking out [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). There are some node modules that will make working with WebSockets quite easy. ([slides](https://de.slideshare.net/julienlapointe/introduction-to-websockets-presentation) | [ws (node module)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws))

Also, for servers in node.js I would recommand taking a look at [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html). ([node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express))

For even more streaming check out [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/)

Comment: I also don't want to keep a connection open but how should I wait till I get a response as I am receiving data in chunks, I am also getting socket hangup error